# Find maximal pairs in a set of tuples

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, set, tuples

I have to develop a recursive Python function that returns the set of all maximal pairs in setpairs.
For instance the maximalpairs({(1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 2)}) shall return {(1, 2), (0, 3)}.

This is my implementation

```
def maximalpairs(pairs):
    if len(pairs)==1:
        return pairs
    for tup1 in pairs:
        for tup2 in pairs:
            if all(i > j for i, j in zip(tup1,tup2)):
                pairs.remove(tup2)
                return maximalpairs(pairs)
        pairs.remove(tup1)
        return maximalpairs(pairs)

pairs={ (1, 0), (0, 3), (1, 2) }
print(maximalpairs(pairs))
```

that returns me just (0,3).
How can I get the correct result?

Comment: What is the definition of "maximal pairs"?

Comment: A pair (x, y) of natural numbers is maximal in a given set of pairs setpairs if it is not dominated by any other pair (w, z) in the set, i.e., it does not hold that: w >= x
and z >= y and at least one of the inequalities is strict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have not really given an explanation of what a maximal pair is, I will assume it's a pair (x,y) such as that y>x. This makes sense seeing your required answer for the example.
Your pairs are lists, so there's no really need to complicate it that much, as you can directly access lists by their indices, aka `tup[0]` or `tup[1]`.
A bit of debugging shows that `tup1 == tup2` is always true for your example. This makes sense, as in each iteration, you're calling again the function, starting everything from scratch, and you're only really executing at most N times (N = length of the set) the inner for, and, at most, once the outer for, as it returns straight away.
For/while loops that will execute once are not really useful, so we'll ditch the outer for. This leaves you with the inner for, that would remain as `for tup in pairs: #Stuff`.
With that, you can't use `zip()` anymore, as you no longer have two tuples, but don't worry. Remembering you can access the elements like in an array, by their indices, the `if` statement can simply end up being such as `if (tup[0] > tup[1]): #Stuff`.
Knowing all of this, the code would remain such as:

```
def maximalpairs(pairs):
    if len(pairs)==1:
        return pairs
    for tup in pairs:
        if (tup[0] > tup[1]):
            pairs.remove(tup)
            return maximalpairs(pairs)
    return pairs
```

This code gives you the expected result, aka `{(1, 2), (0, 3)}`.
If my answer has been helpful, please don't forget to mark it. Thanks!

EDIT:
Okay, to do this you will actually need the double for, as we can't access sets by indices, as they're unordered, and we will need to access two tuples. Let's still not use `zip()`, essentially to avoid problems when `tup1==tup2` (which will always be true at least once).
Let's first have a look at this scenario. My guess is that you don't really need to get also duplicate maximal tuples (aka, if I added once again `(1,2)` to your example, you wouldn't need a result such as `{(0,3),(1,2),(1,2)}`). So, let's avoid this scenario by doing something like:

```py
if (tup2[0] == tup1[0] and tup2[1] == tup1[1]): 
    # Skip the case when tup1==tup2
    continue
```

Now we need to resolve the inequalities. Keep in mind we only need to remove the tuple in one case, when it is dominated by another tuple. Remembering the way we access lists, I understand you would need something like this:

```
if (tup2[0] >= tup1[0] and tup2[1] >= tup1[1]):
    pairs.remove(tup1)
    return maximalpairs(pairs)
```

Therefore, by leaving the code such as:

```
def maximalpairs(pairs):
    if len(pairs)==1:
        return pairs
    for tup1 in pairs:
        for tup2 in pairs:
            if (tup2[0] == tup1[0] and tup2[1] == tup1[1]): 
                # Skip the case when tup1==tup2
                continue
            elif (tup2[0] >= tup1[0] and tup2[1] >= tup1[1]):
                pairs.remove(tup1)
                return maximalpairs(pairs)
    return pairs
```

The result is still the expected one.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation, It's very usefull. I add above the definition of "maximal pairs".

Comment: No problem. Added explanation and possible solution after seeing the meaning of maximal tuple.

Comment: Everything's clear now!  I was close to the solution, thanks you so much.